# gazebo world with roof

Tags: ros, gazebo

Does anybody know of any readily accessible gazebo worlds with a roof?

I have several environments without a roof, and one with a roof (that is too high up for the required purpose), i could do with another. The first floor of any building will do just fine.

Background - I'm testing a 3D mapping package, with a velodyne LiDAR. In the real world the roof of an environment gets compacted down as an obstacle, and I need an environment to tune the parameters to prevent this happening / check that that doesn't happen with this setup.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is preventing you from adding a roof?

Answer (score 2):

There are several world files with enclosed spaces in the Ignition Fuel website:

- https://app.ignitionrobotics.org/fuel/worlds

The Edifice Demo world is indoors, though perhaps the roof is too high

- https://app.ignitionrobotics.org/OpenRobotics/fuel/worlds/Edifice%20demo

Just about all of the sub-T worlds are in tunnels, which have a roof.

- https://app.ignitionrobotics.org/OpenRobotics/worlds/Finals%20Systems%20Preliminary%20Round%202
- https://app.ignitionrobotics.org/OpenRobotics/fuel/worlds/Finals%20Prize%20Round%20World%2004

Comment: Awesome thanks!